# AppleScript countdown

Tags: date, time, formatting, applescript

I want to have a string that counts down from current time to alarm time.

I've manage to figer out how to get the current time and how to set the alarm time.

The problem I'm having is that when I take current time - alarm time it gives me a numer witch I then need to format back to a hh:mm:ss string.

i've got this.

```
set alarmHour to 23
set alarmMinute to 00

set theDate to the current date
set the hours of theDate to alarmHour
set the minutes of theDate to alarmMinute
set the seconds of theDate to 0
theDate

set countdown to theDate - (current date)
set ss to countdown / 60
```

at this point it gives me **22.283333333333** witch i now need to convert to hh:mm:ss and then put them into a sting that give me 00:22:00

UPDATE:
in swift you have % you can use

```
 countDownTime = (formatterInteger - timeControlInteger)
    let interval    = Int(countDownTime)
    let seconds     = interval % 60
    let minutes     = (interval / 60) % 60
    let hours       = (interval / 3600)
```

but how to you do this in applescript?

Comment: In AppleScript integer division ignoring the remainder (`/`) is `div` and the modulo operator `%` is `mod`

Comment: is there a way to format strings like in swift? like String(format:"%02d",absHour)

Comment: Short answer: No. You have to do everything "manually". AppleScript is a scripting rather than a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to second question:**

> is there a way to format strings like in swift? like
>   String(format:"%02d",absHour) – Mathias Halén

Yes, but you need to use the Satimage.osax scripting addition, available for free at:
[Satimage AppleScript Additions](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html)

[Satimage strftime() -- Date/Time Format Function](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/dictionaries/dict_satimage.html#SatimageTextAdditions.strftime)

> strftime v : format a date using a specification string like in the C
>   function strftime.
>
> strftime date or list of date
>
> into string : the formatting string. To obtain ISO 8601 dates, use
>   "%FT%TZ" or "%GW%V-%uT%TZ" (using the 'with GMT' parameter)
>
> [GMT boolean] : if true, output date as GMT. Default: false, the ouput
>   date is local.
>
> → string : the formatted date
>
> EXAMPLE:     strftime (current date) into “%x” RETURNS:     07/22/14

`"%a, %b %d, %Y"          RETURNS:  Tue, Jul 22, 2014
set d to current date
-- some ISO 8601 formats:
strftime d into "%FT%T%z"
-- "2007-01-15T16:10:56+0100"
strftime d into "%GW%V-%uT%T%z"
-- "2007W03-1T16:10:56+0100"
--if you need to store the date d as UTC:
strftime d into "%FT%TZ" with GMT
-- "2007-01-15T15:10:56Z"
strftime d into "%a, %b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %z"
-- "Mon, Jan 15, 2007 16:10:56 +0100"`